# On click get this variable in javascript with these ids

Tags: javascript, php

On click h2 I need this variable `$post_id` in this two places in javascript like I have added with img and input in html.

How can I get this variable in javascript and add with those two ids ?

```
<h2  id="view" data-target="#Modal_<?php echo $post_id;?>"> view  </h2>

<img id="pic<?php echo $post_id; ?> " />

<input id="input<?php echo $post_id; ?>" >
```

js:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#pic').attr('src', e.target.result); // here with #pic
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
}

$("#input").change(function(){                    // here with #input
    readURL(this);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

when li is clicked change the ids.

```
 <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<?php echo $post_slug;?>"><a>View</a></li>

<div id="myModal_<?php echo $post_slug;?>"  >


<input type="file" class="file" id="imgInp<?php echo $post_slug;?>"/>

<img id="blah<?php echo $post_slug;?>"   />

</div>
```

js:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result); // here in id add this blah<?php echo $post_slug;?>
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){   // here in id add this imgInp<?php echo $post_slug;?>
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: You can just read it like `$('#view').data('target')`

Comment: what do you mean "add", do you want to set the ids of object or add the first one to them?

Answer (score 1):

You've to add click event to the `h2` then get the `data-target` using jQuery method **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** and extract the `post_id` from it using `split()` method then set the `id` to the `img/input` using **[`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method :

```
$("h2").on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');

    $('img').prop('id', 'pic'+target);
    $('input').prop('id', 'input'+target);
});
```

You should also adapt the other `event/function` to deal with dynamic `id`'s like :

```
function readURL(input, post_id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#pic'+post_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

// here with all inputs that has the 'id' start with 'input'
$("input[id^='input']").change(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).prop('id').split('input')[1];
    readURL(this, post_id);
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("h2").on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  var post_id = target.split('_')[1]; //Remove the #Modal_

  console.log('---Before', $('img').prop('id'), $('input').prop('id'));
  
  $('img').prop('id', 'pic'+post_id);
  $('input').prop('id', 'input'+post_id);
  
  console.log('---After', $('img').prop('id'), $('input').prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2  id="view" data-target="#Modal_100"> view  </h2>
<img id="pic" />
<input id="input" />
```

Comment: after adding this click function  do i  need to  change  #pic and #input  in the existing  js code ??

Comment: I added the click function.
Should I change  this line  $("#input").change(function(){ to $('input').prop('id').change(function(){

Comment: this what i need what have you done but i  need to change this to ids onclick h2  in the lines where i have pointed .  1. $('#pic').attr('src', e.target.result); // here with #pic    and 2. $("#input").change(function(){

Comment: h2 will be clicked and those 2 ids will be changed   in my code .

Comment: Check my update @Truespeaker... (Downvoters comments helps.)

Comment: I am new in js  and confused about it. i have tried your code but not getting it done. If you have time, please  help me by writing your code inside mine. I am  trying for 3 hours still nothing worked for me. i have updated the question . please combine your  code inside my code .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the elements IMG and INPUT by and incomplete Id as you added a number in your php code.

You can put that data with an data attribute and get it on the javascript with jQuery

php code

```
<h2  id="view" data-target="#Modal_<?php echo $post_id;?>"> view  </h2>

<img id="pic<?php echo $post_id; ?>" />

<input id="input" data-postid="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" >
```

js:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {

            postid = $(input).data("postid"); // will contain $post_id

            $('#pic'+postid).attr('src', e.target.result); // here with #pic
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
}

$("#input").change(function(){                    // here with #input
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: postid = $(this).data("postid"); how this line will contain  $post_id ??

Comment: You're right, I corrected it. The idea is checking for the attribute in the input element.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("view").onclick = function() {
    var img = this.nextSibling;
    var input = img.nextSibling;
    var dataTarget = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    var imgID = img.getAttribute('id');
    var inputID = input.getAttribute('id');
};
```

Comment: Some explanation might help.